# R make a datatable editable after initialization

Tags: r, datatable

I need to initialized data tables. At the moment I have two functions that do very similar things:

```
make_data_table_settings<- function(input_df){

         result_dt <- datatable(input_df,rownames= TRUE,
                      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                     scrollX = TRUE,
                                     lengthMenu = c(10, 20, 50),
                                     pageLength = 10))

          return (result_dt)
 }
```

Now at a different point, I need to make it editable as follows

```
make_data_table_settings_with_editable <- function (input_df){

     result_dt <- datatable(input_df,rownames= TRUE,
                      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                     scrollX = TRUE,
                                     lengthMenu = c(10, 20, 50),
                                     pageLength = 10),
                   editable = list(target = 'row', disable = list(columns = c(0:5)))
                  
                )
    return (result_dt)
  }
```

Is there a way I can link the functions so that I don't have to repeat the first code block?

Essentially I want a flow to work as:

```
result <- make_data_table_settings(my_input_df)
result2 <- make_editable(make_data_table_settings(my_input_df))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I am not misunderstanding your question,

You could just write one function and use `switch` to activate the right option.

EDIT:
OK, thank you for your feedback, @user1357015 ; you could have an additional option to your function (e.g. editableOpt), which if set to false should give you the equivalent of the first function; if set with relevant parameters would give you the second one. Let me know if this helps.

```
make_data_table_Testfx <- function (
  input_df,
  editableOpt = list(
    target = 'row', disable = list(columns = c(0:5)))){
  
  result_dt <- datatable(
    input_df,rownames= TRUE,
    options = list(
      dom = 'Bfrtip', scrollX = TRUE,
      lengthMenu = c(10, 20, 50),
      pageLength = 10), editable = editableOpt)
  
  return (result_dt)
}
```

When running the above, set `editableOpt = FALSE`, and should give you the first function; leave it to default to have it equivalent to the second function.

Best,
Max

Comment: Then I still would have to have almost two identical code blocks. Where one is just slightly longer than the other.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, please see edited answer. Let me know if it works

Comment: Yes, I think this works, accepting thank you.